# Why is the "display" css property not in the default whitelist for the owasp java library?

Tags: html, css, owasp

I am currently using the [owasp java library](https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer) on a backend service in order to sanitize HTML sent from the client.  The owasp java library has a CSS whitelist of css rules that it will allow inside of any style tag inside of html elements.  You can find that whitelist [here](https://owasp-java-html-sanitizer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distrib/javadoc/src-html/org/owasp/html/CssSchema.html#line.761).

One thing that I noticed about this whitelist is that the `display` property is omitted.  This means that if I create HTML code like the following:

```
<div style="margin-left:0px;display:none;"></div>
```

then the HTML sanitizer with the default styling whitelist will strip out the display rule and the HTML saved on the server will be:

```
<div style="margin-left:0px;"></div>
```

Why is the `display` property not white-listed by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because then the other white-listed styles wouldn't work due to the element not being displayed at all

**UPDATE**

> `display` has a lot of weird edge cases that affect layout in weird
>   ways.
>
> `inline`, `block`, and `inline-block` are likely safe in most contexts.
>
> `fixed` is probably safe in none.
>
> `table` and others are probably dodgy since there may be ways to break
>   visual containment.
>
> Even `block` and `inline block` can break visual containment for example
>   with a policy that only allows inline tags when the embedder fixes the
>   `width` of the container and doesn't hide `overflow`.

[Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/owasp-java-html-sanitizer-support/WbmmRYOT6eY)

Comment: What if you need any other property values: "inline, inline-block, block"?

Comment: What if it was display:inline-block instead of display:none?  The owasp sanitizer would still take it out